.net maui popup not showing unless app is running
i am using hce in maui, which all works well, code below shows what i am doing. the hce system work well but the popup is not showing when in background, it only shows when running the app.
[
    Service(Enabled = true, Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE"),
    IntentFilter(new[] { global::Android.Nfc.CardEmulators.HostApduService.ServiceInterface }),
    MetaData(global::Android.Nfc.CardEmulators.HostApduService.ServiceMetaData, Resource = "@xml/apduservice")
]
public class MyHostApduService : HostApduService
{
    public override void OnDeactivated([GeneratedEnum] DeactivationReason reason)
    {

    }

    public override byte[]? ProcessCommandApdu(byte[]? commandApdu, Bundle? extras)
    {

        var task = Task.Run<string>(async () => await SecureStorage.GetAsync("text"));
        task.Wait();
        var result = task.Result;
        byte[]? bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
        _ = ShowPopup();
        return bytes;
        
    }

    public async Task ShowPopup()
    {
       
        var ConformationPopControl = new ConfirmationPopUpPage();
        ConformationPopControl.Title = "Sent";         
       
        Convert.ToBoolean(await PopupAction.DisplayPopup(ConformationPopControl));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        PopupAction.ClosePopup(ConformationPopControl);
    }
}

public class PopupAction
{
 public static async Task<T> DisplayPopup<T>(PopUpBasePage page) where T : new()
 {
     try
     {
         if (Application.Current?.MainPage != null)
         {
             await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
         }
         return (T)await page.returnResultTask.Task;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return default(T);
     }
 }

 public static async Task<object> DisplayPopup(PopUpBasePage page)
 {
     try
     {
         if (Application.Current?.MainPage != null)
            
             await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);

         return await page.returnResultTask.Task;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return "";
     }
 }

 public static async Task ClosePopup(object returnValue = null)
 {
     if (Application.Current?.MainPage != null && Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count > 0)
     {
         try
         {
             var currentPage = (PopUpBasePage)Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.LastOrDefault();
             currentPage?.returnResultTask.TrySetResult(returnValue);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..");
     }
 }

}
however i want to show a popup when the data has been sent but this only works when the app is running not in background. is there a way around this.

Generally you would use a local notification to alert the user when your app is backgrounded.  Showing a popup when the user is actively using another app is really bad UX

hi the idea was to show a page or popup when the apdu data has sent, the same as when a payment has been made. can that be done with local notification.
